# problem consuming service with JAX-WS, wlsd:import and # URL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, ws-security

i'm trying to consume a SOAP Service in Java 11.
I've created my classes using `com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3.2`, that's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.m2sc</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc-ws-consumer-j11</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        ...
    </build>
</project>
```

when I try to start my test program i got some warning like

```
WARNING: Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.
```

and an error

```
SEVERE: WSP1005: Failed to find policy referenced by URI "http://int-vwe1c01.m2sc.local:8080/EngageOneWS/DeliveryService?wsdl#WSPolicy".
```

in `DeliveryService.wsdl` i found the import of WSPolcy

```
<wsdl:import location="http://int-vwe1c01.m2sc.local:8080/EngageOneWS/DeliveryService?wsdl=ws-policy.xml" namespace="http://pb.com/EngageOne/ws/WSPolicy"/>
```

and references

```
<wsdl:binding name="DeliveryServiceSOAP" type="DeliveryService">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSPolicy"/>
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
...
</wsdl:binding>
```

I tried to import ws-policy.xml as separate wsdl using

```
<configuration>
   <wsdlUrls>
      <wsdlUrl>http://int-vwe1c01.m2sc.local:8080/EngageOneWS/DeliveryService?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
      <wsdlUrl>http://int-vwe1c01.m2sc.local:8080/EngageOneWS/DeliveryService?wsdl=ws-policy.xml</wsdlUrl>
   </wsdlUrls>
   <quiet>true</quiet>
</configuration>
```

but it wont work.
I made a try switching library, using Apache CXF 3.5.4 and it's works fine so I thins JAX-WS not handle URL starting with "#" correctly. It`s a major switch to go with CXF, I prefere to stay with JAX-WS.

Someon can help me pls ?

Comment: FYI: the problem seems to be how JAX-WS handles references with "#" on imported WSDLs, using Apache CXF the problem does not arise